# Addition of decimal values in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following numerical array:

```
var numberArray: number[] = [2.15, 0.72, 2.15, 0.72, 0.72];
```

where the sum of the values is 6.46. However, if I also run:

```
var Total = numberArray.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;});
```

I always get 6.459999999999999.

I have a numerical array with about 1000 values and when I try and get the total of these my numbers are way off and I think this is the reason. How can I get this to aggregate properly?

Comment: What do you mean by the total being "way off"? Is it off by `0.0000000000001`?

Comment: `var Total = numberArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0).toFixed(2);`? Perhaps!

Comment: @ConnorsFan "I have a numerical array with about 1000 values and when I try and get the total of these my numbers are way off." The error gets larger the more numbers I have any my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **toFixed()** method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
const numberArray: number[] = [2.15, 0.72, 2.15, 0.72, 0.72];
const Total = numberArray.reduce((a, b) => {return a + b;});
console.log(Total.toFixed(2));
```